# Unable to use SED to edit files fast

Tags: sed

The file is initially

```
$cat so/app.yaml 
application: SO
...
```

I run the following command. I get an empty file.

```
$sed s/SO/so/ so/app.yaml > so/app.yaml 
$cat so/app.yaml 
$
```

**How can you use SED to edit the file and not giving me an empty file?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$ sed -i -e's/SO/so/' so/app.yaml
```

The `-i` means in-place.

Comment: From the man-page: It is not recommended to give a zero-length extension when in-place editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content in situations where disk space is exhausted, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I have been struggling with this for the last thirty minutes.

Comment: In case this does not work for you: the version of `sed` you're using probably does not support `-i` -- eg, in Solaris.  Often where this is the case there'll be a `gsed` somewhere that supports it.

Comment: `-i` isn't supported on AIX systems. The workaround is to output it to a tmp file and then copy it to the file you want modified.

Answer (score 5):

The `>` used in piping will open the output file when the pipes are all set up, i.e. before command execution. Thus, the input file is truncated prior to `sed` executing. This is a problem with all shell redirection, not just with `sed`.

Sheldon Young's answer shows how to use in-place editing.

Comment: It seems that Young's way is the only one. I tried the following code too unsuccessfully `sed s/ABC/abc/ settings.py` > settings.py.

Comment: I think the use of `>` that @Rob is suggesting is to output it to a tmp file and then copy it back. `sed s/ABC/abc/ settings.py > tmp; cp tmp settings.py`

Answer (score 5):

You are using the wrong tool for the job. [`sed`](http://OpenGroup.Org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html) is a *stream* editor (that's why it's called **s**`ed`), so it's for in-flight editing of streams in a pipe. [`ed`](http://OpenGroup.Org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ed.html) OTOH is a *file* editor, which can do everything `sed` can do, except it works on files instead of streams. (Actually, it's the other way round: `ed` is the original utility and `sed` is a clone that avoids having to create temporary files for streams.)

`ed` works very much like `sed` (because `sed` is just a clone), but with one important difference: you can move around in files, but you can't move around in streams. So, all commands in `ed` take an address parameter that tells `ed`, *where* in the file to apply the command. In your case, you want to apply the command *everywhere* in the file, so the address parameter is just `,` because `a,b` means "from line `a` to line `b`" and the default for `a` is `1` (beginning-of-file) and the default for `b` is `$` (end-of-file), so leaving them both out means "from beginning-of-file to end-of-file". Then comes the `s` (for substitute) and the rest looks much like `sed`.

So, your `sed` command `s/SO/so/` turns into the ed command `,s/SO/so/`.

And, again because `ed` is a file editor, and more precisely, an interactive file editor, we also need to write (`w`) the file and quit (`q`) the editor.

This is how it looks in its entirety:

```
ed -- so/app.yaml <<-HERE
    ,s/SO/so/
    w
    q
HERE
```

See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703459/#703535) to a similar question.

What happens in your case, is that executing a pipeline is a two-stage process: first construct the pipeline, then run it. `>` means "open the file, *truncate* it, and connect it to filedescriptor 1 (`stdout`)". *Only then* is the pipe actually run, i.e. sed is executed, but at this time, the file has already been truncated.

Some versions of `sed` also have a `-i` parameter for in-place editing of files, that makes `sed` behave a little more like `ed`, but using that is not advisable: first of all, it doesn't support all the features of `ed`, but more importantly, it is a non-standardized proprietary extension of GNU `sed` that doesn't work on many non-GNU systems. It's been a while since I used a non-GNU system, but last I used one, neither Solaris nor OpenBSD nor HP-UX nor IBM AIX `sed` supported the `-i` parameter.

Comment: "proprietary extension of GNU sed" @Jörg: Do you mean that GNU makes money by selling their codes? I have always had an idea that anybody can use GNU software for free which follows GNU licence (i.e. you need to publish your code free for others if use GNU code).

Comment: That's not what I meant. English is not my first language, maybe "proprietary" is the wrong word. I mean that '-i' is only available in GNU sed, and is not part of the POSIX/SUS standard, so GNU can redefine '-i' in whichever way they want, other vendors can implement '-i' anyway *they* want ...

Comment: ... or not implement it at all. And there is no definition of what '-i' means, except the source code of GNU sed. My university used to use HP-UX on their servers, and the #1 problem for students was that they tried to use things like 'sed -i' or 'bash' or whatever that they knew from their ...

Comment: ... Linux systems and it didn't work, simply because they don't *exist* on HP-UX.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that redirecting output into the same file you are editing is causing your problem.

You need redirect standard output to some temporary file and when sed is done overwrite the original file by the temporary one.

Comment: How can you do that as an one-liner without leaving dummy files to the folder?

Comment: Well, folder "/tmp" is for dummy files. So it could be something like this: sed s/SO/so so/app.yaml > /tmp/tmp321 ; mv -f /tmp/tmp321 so/app.yaml