# bash scripting: change certain lines in a text file based on it's location

Tags: bash, scripting

I have bunch of sub-folders following the naming pattern x1, x2, x3, x4 ... and each containing the same script.sh file. What if I want to write a script, that changes certain line (say line 2) of that script file from x1 to whatever the folder's name is?

So for example, in folder x5, the 2nd line of script.sh should be x5, and in folder x39, the second line of script.sh should be x39.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I replace a specific line by line number in a text file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703459/how-can-i-replace-a-specific-line-by-line-number-in-a-text-file)

Comment: would you like to replace or insert that line?

Comment: @BroSlow That's not a very good duplicate. Replacimg with the folder name is a significant additional requirement.

Comment: @tripleee Maybe not an exact duplicate, but I would guess there are at least 10 good questions that fulfill the other 'requirement'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one inserts the sub-folder name to the 2nd line of each script.sh

```
find . -name script.sh | while read f
do
    dir=$(basename $(dirname "$f"))
    sed -i "2 i $dir" "$f"
done
```

to replace the 2nd line, use `c` instead of `i`

```
find . -name script.sh | while read f
do
    dir=$(basename $(dirname "$f"))
    sed -i "2 c $dir" "$f"
done
```

Comment: A number of issues with this. Don't do `for f in $(find)` (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7039579/3076724) for better syntax. Also, you're not checking subfolder names (so this could change unintended files, and I'm not sure sure subfolder == recursive). Also, quote your variables, both in subshells and by themselves.

Comment: @BroSlow, thanks! I've updated the answer per your suggestion. please edit if you see anything else problematic

Comment: it doesn't actually replace the 2nd line, but it inserts at the 2nd line. could you tell me how to replace?